How do I change language in the Windows Recovery Environment?
I have two preferred languages in Settings: English and Swedish. The Windows display language is English.
When you restart Windows 11 by pressing Shift and clicking Restart, Windows boots up to the Windows Recovery Environment, WinRE. Here, different options on how to proceed are shown. This dialog on my PC is in Swedish.
How can I change this dialog to English?
I've executed the Command Prompt commands
bcdedit /set {current} locale en-US
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} locale en-US

I've also set Language for non-Unicode programs in intl.cpi to English. The region settings in Settings->Time & lamguage->Language & regions: Country or region and Regional format are both set to Swedish. I suppose these settings are not used in WinRE because I need them. I may temporarily change them to English to evaluate the result, but I doubt it would solve the problem.

You delete the recovery image and recreate it and specify you want the English WinRE instead of the Swedish WinRE.

@Ramhound: Okay. How do you delete the recovery image? How do you recreate it? Where do you specify that you want the English WinRE?

Here is how you customize the image.  How you delete and recreate the partition is well documented.

@Ramhound: Thank you. I don't have the technician computer with ADK and WinPE and I'm not familiar with the required procedures. It's too complicated. I give up unless there is a simpler way.

If you want to customize the image you will have to install it.

@Ramhound: I've added a comment to harrymc. Can you look at it? I might have come one step further but the problem is not solved.

I have given you all the information required to accomplish your task

This is from
Windows 10 Recovery Environment Language :

After few weeks of trying i finally found solution.
In short - change language in bcdedit / windows / settings / sysprep /
regedit and etc. won't work.
You just need to replace your current winre.wim file to the one from
Windows that have language that you prefer.
I did it simply, download Windows 10 Pro Eng ISO and extract it. Then
mount /sources/install.esd file and it creates install.wim - here
you go to /Windows/System32/Recovery and cut the winre.wim file
and move it to your system.
Well, it's almost done. Run cmd by admin and use command:
reagentc /setreimage /path C:\windows\system32\recovery

After that one more:
reagentc /enable

Here it is. After that i restart my laptop and go to RE in Safe Mode
and it become totally on English.


It may be correct. winre.wim is located under C:\Recovery. You cannot step into this folder so winre.wim is unreachable. I've downloaded Win11 ISO but I think I give up. It's too complicated and not worth the effort.

@KalleSvensson - It shouldn't be in that folder.  If it is, then it's not in a standard location, and you should move it

Wrong. winre.wim is in another place and is accessible. I'll consider it again.

It can also be in C:\Recovery\OEM\winre.wim for an OEM installation. Details may change, so please try the answer but verify details as you go along.

@harrymc: I have two identical laptops and one has WinRE dialog in English. I copied winre.wim from this laptop to the target PC. But there, the WinRE dialog is still in Swedish. winre.wim is located in C:$WinREAgent\Backup. Apparently it is not the one used at startup.

The laptops were upgraded from Windows 10. I also have another PC, a desktop, that was bought with preinstalled Windows 11. There is no winre.wim on this PC. I've started suspecting that the above solution only works on Windows 10. On Windows 11 there is no winre.wim and the WinRE dialog is implemented in another file. I certainly have this file but don't know which one it is.

Try Reagentc /disable to remove winre.wim from its partition, then replace winre.wim under Windows/System32/Recovery or Windows/System32/Recovery or C:\Recovery\OEM\winre.wim or similar. Finally do Reagentc /enable to put it back in its partition..

@harrymc: I've tried everything. I followed your recent advice. I followed the way indicated in your answer. Finally, I reloaded Windows. The language in WinRE is still Swedish.

There must be something we're missing here, because your description, taken at face value, is just impossible. Let's perhaps use a big gun : Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade, ensuring that you're using a pure English ISO.

@harrymc - No, it certainly should be possible but the author doesn’t have what is necessary to perform the action installed on their machine

The answer by @harrymc is correct. I'm adding some details.
WinRE is a separate, slimmed-down Windows version, so manipulating Windows parameters does not affect it. WinRE is implemented by means of the image file winre.wim. It normally resides in the recovery partition. To change the WinRE language, you have to replace winre.wim with an image in the right language.

Get new winre.wim
Download the ISO image of Windows 11. Open it with File Explorer. It creates a new pseudo-drive, say D: Copy the Windows installation image install.wim to a directory of your choice.
copy D:\sources\install.wim C:\Temp

Mount install.wim and extract winre.wim
Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:C:\Temp\install.wim /Index:1 /MountDir:C:\Temp\WinRE
copy C:\Temp\WinRE\Windows\System32\Recovery\Winre.wim  C:\Temp

Clean up.
Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:C:\Temp\WinRE /Commit    
del C:\Temp\install.wim


Register the new image
reagentc /disable
reagentc /setreimage /path C:\Temp
reagentc /enable



After this operation winre.wim disappears from C:\Temp.
Honestly, I didn't get winre.wim from the ISO file. I copied it from another similar PC, where it was in English. It is better because an OEM can add drivers and modules necessary for the PC. winre.wim resided in the recovery partition. Getting a copy of it from there is whole science. Microsoft made it nearly impossible. It could be the subject of another question.

@zx485: Thank you for improving my text. You must be using some magic. I tried hard but couldn't get the formatting right.

Glad I could help. For first level lists, the indentation of text is 4 spaces and 7 spaces for code sections. For second level lists, it's....... I guess I have to try myself ;-) --- The 4 spaces for many lines at once can be created by selecting them and then pressing CTRL-K.
